# Widget is disposed exception when detaching and reattaching parts

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, e4

We've been looking into a `Widget is disposed` exception that is quite strange.

I've created a basic example.

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu;

public class TestView {

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct(final Composite parent) {

        final Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);

        final Menu menu = new Menu(composite);

        composite.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseDown(final MouseEvent e) {

                System.out.println(menu.isDisposed());

                menu.setVisible(true); // Widget is disposed exception
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This has been added to a part stack with these settings.

[image: TestView application.e4xmi settings]

**Steps to recreate:**

1. Detach `TestView`
2. Close `TestView`
3. Reopen `TestView` (Using `partService.showPart("TestViewId", PartState.ACTIVATE)`)
4. Reattach `TestView`
5. Click in `TestView`

A `Widget is disposed` exception is thrown due to the menu being disposed.

I added a dispose listener to the menu item. It is disposed when the part is reattached to the part stack. It seems to be that when the shell is disposed it is also disposing the menu.

Here is the stack trace when it is disposed.

```
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
    at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1336)
    at TestView$1.widgetDisposed(TestView.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4131)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1055)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1060)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.releaseChildren(Decorations.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.releaseChildren(Shell.java:1353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.dispose(Decorations.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.dispose(Shell.java:742)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.disposeWidget(SWTPartRenderer.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeRemoveGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:958)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$1(PartRenderingEngine.java:886)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:881)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.removeGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.subscribeTopicToBeRendered(PartRenderingEngine.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.di.internal.extensions.EventObjectSupplier$DIEventHandler.handleEvent(EventObjectSupplier.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.UIElementImpl.setToBeRendered(UIElementImpl.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.cleanupaddon.CleanupAddon.lambda$1(CleanupAddon.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3919)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3550)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1474)
```

I've tried adding other components (E.g. Buttons) and they don't get disposed. It seems to be that this only happens to the menu.

What could be causing this?

Comment: I think setting a menu on the Composite passed to @PostConstruct is wrong. The only thing you should do with that composite is add a child Composite that your code uses.

Comment: I've created a composite first using the parent composite and the same error occurs. I've updated my question.

Comment: What exactly are you doing in 'detach' and 'reattach'?

Comment: Right click and selecting detach. This moves the part into a separate window. I then close the window it's contained in, reopen it (using the code mentioned above), and drag it back into the stack part.

Comment: Could this be a bug? Unless I've added the Menu incorrectly I'm struggling to see what I could be doing wrong.

Comment: I can reproduce it, it does look like a bug which should be reported on [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/)

Comment: Okay I'll do that now. Thanks for looking into it :)

Comment: @greg-449 do you have any ideas for a workaround for this?